# Display form input values from one page to another

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have two (2) pages. One is a Create page and the other one is a Confirm page. Create page has a form and a "Proceed to Confirm" button which will redirect to Confirm page. Confirm page should display all the inputs from the Create page, then the user will be able to submit it right after once he/she has checked all the inputted values.

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    return ('pages.create');    
}

public function confirmCreate()
{
    $value = Input::all();
    Session::flash('value', $value);
    return view('pages.confirm-create')->with('value', $value);
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('create', 'MyController@create')->name('create');

Route::post('confirm-create', 'MyController@confirmCreate')->name('confirm-create');

Route::put('store', 'MyController@store')->name('store');
```

Create page View:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'confirm-create',
                                'method' => 'POST', 
                                'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label required">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name) }}" required autofocus>
        @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contactNumber') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label required">Contact Number</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="contactNumber" placeholder="Contact Number" type="text" class="form-control" name="contactNumber" value="{{ old('contactNumber) }}" required autofocus>
        @if ($errors->has('contactNumber'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('contactNumber') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Proceed to Confirm
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Confirm page View:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'pages',
                                'method' => 'POST', 
                                'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label required">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">{{ old('name') }}</label>
        @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contactNumber') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label required">Contact Number</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">{{ old('contactNumber') }}</label>
        @if ($errors->has('contactNumber'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('contactNumber') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I can't seem to display the data from my Create page (after clicking "Proceed to Confirm" button) to my Confirm page. How should my controller, routes, and view (both Create and Confirm pages) look like? Send help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `value` to `pages.confirm-create` view but don't use it.

Substitute `{{ old('contactNumber') }}` with `{{ $value['contactNumber'] }}` or `{{ $value['contactNumber'] }}`.

Using `old()` is good when you have validation, it gets value from previous request rather than from a value passed to a view.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said but my Confirm page is still empty. Is my create page action url ( `url => 'confirm-create'` ) correct?

Comment: Also, I think my controller is still lacking something or still incorrect.

Comment: Add `<?php var_dump($values); ?>` at the top of `confirm-create.blade.php` to verify it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a small mistake on the `Confirm Page` view.

Old Input cannot be used like that. Have a look at the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input

Which states that:

> Laravel allows you to keep input from one request during the next request. This feature is particularly useful for re-populating forms after detecting validation errors.

It is only used for the same form from where the validation issue has occurred.

Also you are using:

```
<label class="control-label">{{ old('name') }}</label>
```

Instead of  input field.

```
<input id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $value['name'] }}" required autofocus>
```

You need to use `$value['name']` instead of `old('name')`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I used `<input>` in my Create page and not in Confirm page. I used the `<label>` in the Confirm page though.

Comment: Okey. So, have you tried to test whether the value comes in your view or not? you could check by `{{ dd($value) }} ` to find if any value have been passed or not